# PHP Array not returning proper value

Tags: php

I have an array

```
$row['sku'] = '12345';
$row['name'] = 'Spaceballs';
```

When I `var_dump` the whole array, I get all values.  But if I try to get just `$row['sku']` I get `NULL`.  Any idea what could cause this problem?

EDIT:
I'm trying to sort through a rather large product CSV.  The code in question is here:

```
$fieldColumns = fgetcsv($file); // Getting the first row with column descriptors
$r = fgetcsv($file); // This is looped, grabs the next row containing values
$row = array_combine($fieldColumns, $r);  // Merging the two arrays
var_dump($row,$row['sku']);die();  // Exactly like in my code, the 'sku' is dumping NULL
```

The CSV in question is like this:

```
sku,name,etc
12345,Spaceballs,etc
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? https://3v4l.org/K23vE not reproducible there.

Comment: show us the full code

Comment: maybe you've overrided the array somewhere else?

Comment: please update your question and show the full code

Comment: What line endings are your CSV file using?

Comment: Even with what you added in the edit, that code should work, in theory.

Comment: @kmoser DOS line endings.

Comment: @Don'tPanic In theory it should, but I keep getting null on the $row['sku'].

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to imply was that there still isn't enough info here in the question to know why that's happening.

Comment: What is the contents of ``$r`` immediately after the call to ``$r = fgetcsv($file)``? Can you ``var_dump()`` it?

Comment: Further digging showed that whatever created the CSV file I was using created some extra junk before sku, junk I couldn't actually see.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't show what you get from var_dump (`var_dump($row,$row['sku']);`) and don't provide the full PHP script it is imposible to find out where is a problem.

For me it works without problems:

source.csv:

```
sku,name
12345,Spaceballs
321,test1
654,test2
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
if (false !== ($file = fopen('source.csv', 'r'))) {
    $header = fgetcsv($file);
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
        $row = array_combine($header, $row);
        var_dump($row, $row['sku']);
    }
} else
    echo "Can't open the CSV file!";
```

Answer (score 0):

I dug around and the system transfering the files didn't know how to handle UTF-8 encoding and added some junk character to the beginning of the file.  The output I would get would show two sku elements.  The var_dump gave me a string(6) for the first element and a string(3) for the second, confirming this.  A quick run through dos2unix fixed the problem.